# Pin tabs in Chrome that reopen on startup

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, pinning

I'm thinking about moving over to Chrome full time

one of the features i like the most is the "pin tab" how ever im frustrated that when i close the browser and reopen it the pinned tabs open to what was last on the page and not what originally pinned (gmail, timesheet, wiki , etc)

is there anyway to do something similar to firefox4's app tab?

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into the Options page, there is an `On Startup` option in the `Basics` tab. In this, you can set any number of pages to open when Chrome starts.

[image]

Comment: The OP is specifically asking whether pinned tabs can remember the last page they were on. I don't think this is possible, because there is really nothing to be "configured" about Chrome. (Which is why I'll happily keep using Firefox 4.0b2.)

Comment: @Paul: I understood the opposite - he wants the tabs to remember their original state, not the last state they had.

Comment: you are correct. I want my gmail tab to stay gmail everytime i open it.

Comment: @Crash893: In which case, set gmail as a url in the panel shown above and it should always open when you open your browser.

Comment: But the tab won't be pinned anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, it looks like someone has written an extension to do it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forever-pinned/nigigpmchbpkjjgncmpiggfnikllldlh?hl=en-GB